# How do I convert Javascript number variable to a specific word?

Tags: javascript, html

I have built out a Javascript calculator - which will help someone decide what type of investor they are based off their answers to 5 questions. Each answer to each question is assigned a value (1-5 points). As they are completing the quiz, their "points" are added up and displayed in a div.

Right now, the points integer is displayed in the div via:`divobj.innerHTML = "Total Risk Points: "+totalRiskPoints;` and is displayed as the integer value (sum of all points per each answer)

I want to convert the total risk point integer value into a word, for example - if the user's total risk points add up to 25 - I want it to display: "Aggressive Portfolio".

So essentially, I need something that converts the integer to a specified word.

Here is a link to the calculator - you can view the source from there.
https://abgira.com/sites/all/themes/bluez-7.x-1.0/bluez/riskassessment.html

Comment: What have _you_ **tried** upto now?

Comment: `if (totalRiskPoints == 25) divobj.innerHTML = "Total Risk Points: "+totalRiskPoints;` ?

Comment: Do a map lookup for specific integer matches and use `if` conditions for ranges.

Comment: Is there a specific string for every integer value or is this a range type of thing? For example (and a huge hint): `if (totalRiskPoints >= 25)`. And include the *relevant* code in your question - links have a habit of going dead.

Comment: Nicolas and Matt - THANK YOU!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simple...

I don't know what your ranges are for your different types of portfolios but you may change the numbers accordingly.

```
// 0-9 points
if (totalRiskPoints >= 0 && totalRiskPoints < 10) {
    divobj.innerHTML = "Newbie Portfolio";
// 10-24 points
} else if (totalRiskPoints >= 10 && totalRiskPoints < 25) {
    divobj.innerHTML = "Amateur Portfolio";
// 25-infinity points
} else if (totalRiskPoints >= 25) {
    divobj.innerHTML = "Aggressive Portfolio";
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP wanted. They want to display some string associated with the value of `totalRiskPoints` *instead* (or maybe as well as) the `totalRiskPoints`.

Comment: Fixed that up to use a string.

Comment: You code will fail if, for example, `totalRiskPoints === 10`

Comment: Fixed it again haha. It all depends on what ranges he wants for his portfolio types.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your quick help! This did it for me!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use an `if` statement for the `totalRiskPoints`:

```
function calculateTotal()
{
    var totalRiskPoints = getQuestion1() + getQuestion2() + getQuestion3() + getQuestion4() + getQuestion5();

    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='block';

    if (totalRiskPoints === 25)
        divobj.innerHTML = "Aggressive Portfolio";
    else
        divobj.innerHTML = "Total Risk Points: "+totalRiskPoints;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a if-else statement for this case.
If you want one String per integer value, I would recommend a switch-case.

```
var totalRiskPoints = 25;
var result;
if (totalRiskPoints >= 25) {
    result = "Aggressive Portfolio";
} else if (totalRiskPoints >= 20){
    result = "Average Portfolio";
} else if (totalRiskPoints >= 10){
    result = "Safe Portfolio";
}
document.getElementById("divobj").innerHTML = ("Total Risk Points: "+result);
```

Here is a jsfiddle you can play with: http://jsfiddle.net/ux07bb4b/